# Solution for the sequence of the number of "major flaps" in origami bases and its relation to other sequences

Tags: origami-folding

I have recently been getting into origami and reading Robert J. Lang's (a physicist and one of the leading modern origami artist) books. In the book *Origami Design Secrets* he showed a sequence of more and more complicated origami bases (the starting points for many origami creations).

[Here are the first 5 elements of sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TypMv.png)

The basic unit in the base is the right isosceles triangle with two perpendicular folds in it, and you can see it tiled across the bases appearing $2^n$ times in the $n$-th element of the sequence.

Loosely speaking, the $n$-th base is created by tiling the $(n-2)$-th base 4 times in a square pattern. Lang claimed a correspondence between the circular arcs that can be drawn that span the previously described right isosceles triangles (shown in the image) and the number of major "flaps" to use in an origami creation. Each circle, partial or otherwise, corresponds to a flap.

The pattern goes 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 13, 25 for the first few. I looked up this sequence on OEIS and found nothing, which was a novel experience for me. Does anybody have any ideas how to generalize this sequence and find a closed form solution? Does anybody see any relations to other sequences in geometry? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MO! Seems like a cool question, but I think some details and definitions are lacking. It is very hard (for me) to understand the premise and the question as it is, without, well, reading the whole book

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I realized what you said when attempting to explain it to a friend. I had gotten too caught up in the origami aspect of it and didn't flesh out the important details enough. I found it almost impossible to explain without pictures due to my own limitations as an explainer, so I hope you can take a look at the image. The main part is the circular arcs. The n+2th term in the sequence is found by a square tiling of the nth term. The corresponding integers are the number of full or partial distinct circular arcs

Comment: @AmirSagiv Hopefully you can see this from the image? If not, please let me know.

Comment: The sequence of first differences, $1,2,1,4,4,12$, appears three times in the OEIS. Maybe just coincidence, but maybe one of them connects with your sequence. http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C1%2C4%2C4%2C12&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's up, Subhasish! (I'm actually the friend Subhasish mentioned to @AmirSagiv)

To start off with, the first couple terms of the sequence I found with my solution were: $1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 13, 25, 41, 81, 145, 289$.

I found a solution that starts working from the third term. However, it uses a different function for odds and evens.

The first two terms are $1$ and $2$.

Afterwords, odd-indices can be solved with $f(n) = 2^{n-3} + 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}} + 1 = (2^{\frac{n-3}{2}} + 1)^2$

and even-indices with $f(n) = 2^{n-3} + 2^{\frac{n-2}{2}} + 1 = (2^{\frac{n-4}{2}} + 1)^2 + 2^{n-4}$

As @SubhasishMukherjee pointed out in a comment, both of these functions can be consolidated into one form using the ceiling function: $f(n) = 2^{n−3} + 2^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil - 1}+1$.

However, the two separated out formulas are meaningful in their own right. Comparing the sequence and the two functions, you can notice some interesting patterns. Every odd-index term is a square, and the difference between an odd index term and the subsequent even-index term is a power of 4. More specifically, starting from the $n=3$ and $n=5$ pair, the powers of 4 are consecutive powers of 4. Both of these patterns have geometric interpretations that can be noticed if you draw out a few more terms of the sequence.

My solution was a little long, and to be honest, writing math out takes me forever. So I will talk in person with Subhasish (after he wakes up) and some other friends. If we can confirm or disprove my idea then we will edit what I wrote so far.

If anybody online can help to check my work that would be much appreciated as well!

Comment: Hey Shawnak! Thanks so much for this wonderfully written solution. What you wrote can be consolidated as $f_n = 2^{n-3}+2^{\lceil n/2\rceil - 1}+1$, but I think separating them out leads to more interesting conclusions as you noted. It's a mostly intellectual question that sprung from origami folding, which makes it all the more intriguing.

Comment: Thanks @SubhasishMukherjee! I'll edit my answer to add in the consolidated solution, and I totally agree that the other forms are interesting in their own right.